# Annotate every obj of QuerySet with count of every choice of related obj, grouped by choice value

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Let's say I have two models:

```py
class Mailing(models.Model):
    ...


class Message(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=aware_utc_now)

    class DeliveryStatusChoices(models.TextChoices):  # Number of choices may vary.
        PENDING = 'pending'
        SUCCESS = 'success'
        FAIL = 'fail'

    status = models.CharField(
        choices=DeliveryStatusChoices.choices,
        default=DeliveryStatusChoices.PENDING,
        max_length=50
    )

    mailing = models.ForeignKey(
        'Mailing',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='messages'
    )
```

I'm looking for a way to annotate mailings with count of related messages grouped by choice value. To be able to do something like:

```py
mailing.stats
```

and get:

```py
{'pending': 15, 'success': 20, 'fail': 2}
```

Only messages related to particular mailing should be counted.

I found out how to get stats for particular mailing:

```py
models.Message.objects.filter(mailing_id=1).values('status').annotate(count=Count('status'))
```

the output is:

```py
<QuerySet [{'status': 'pending', 'count': 5}, {'status': 'success', 'count': 2}, {'status': 'fail', 'count': 3}]>
```

`annotate` cannot be called on particular object. So, for loop won't work.
Also output format is not as desired. But it's ok.

Another way I found:

```py
result = []
for mailing in models.Mailing.objects.all():
    statuses = mailing.messages.values('status').annotate(count=Count('status'))

    mailing_result = {'id': mailing.id}
    for status in statuses:
        mailing_result[status['status']] = status['count']
    result.append(mailing_result)
```

But this solution gives me just list of dicts.

Sometimes I have to prefetch related objects based on some criteria:

```py
messages = Prefetch(
    'messages',
    models.Message.objects.filter(
        date_created__gte=yesterday_midnight,
        date_created__lt=today_midnight
    )
)

mailings = models.Mailing.objects.prefetch_related(messages)
```

In this case I'd like to generate stats by counting only prefetched messages.
For example, if some mailing has 20 messages, but only 15 meet the criteria, than mailing should be annotated with stats for that 15 messages.

**UPD**: I came up with

```py
models.Mailing.objects.annotate(
    stats=Value(
        dict(Subquery(
            models.Message.objects.filter(
                mailing_id=OuterRef('id')
            ).values_list('status').annotate(
                count=Count('status')
            )
        )),
        output_field=JSONField()
    )
)
```

but got

```py
'Subquery' object is not iterable
```

**UPD 2**: Another idea. Very inefficient I think.

```py
qs = models.Mailing.objects.none()
for mailing in models.Mailing.objects.all():
    item = models.Mailing.objects.filter(id=mailing.id).annotate(
        stats=Value(
            dict(models.Message.objects.filter(
                mailing_id=mailing.id
            ).values_list('status').annotate(
                count=Count('status')
            )),
            output_field=JSONField()
        )
    )
    qs |= item
```

However, the problem is that every mailing in `qs` has the same value of `.stats` as the first one.

For example, if the first mailing's stats is `{'success': 2, 'fail': 5}` all other mailings has the same, despite not sharing the same object (`qs[0].stats == qs[1].stats -> True, qs[0].stats is qs[1].stats -> False`)

The only solution I found is to replace QuerySet (`qs = models.Mailing.objects.none()`) with python list (`[]`)

```py
qs = []
for mailing in models.Mailing.objects.all():
    item = models.Mailing.objects.filter(id=mailing.id).annotate(
        stats=Value(
            dict(models.Message.objects.filter(
                mailing_id=mailing.id
            ).values_list('status').annotate(
                count=Count('status')
            )),
            output_field=JSONField()
        )
    )
    qs.append(item[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```py
from django.db.models import Q, Count

mailings = Mailing.objects.annotate(
    pending_messages_count = Count(
        'messages', 
        filter = Q(messages__status = 'pending')
    ),
    success_messages_count = ...
)
```

**EDIT:**

You can create a dictionary of annotations like so, and then unpack them in your queryset:

```py
annotations = {
    status + '_message_count' : Count(
        status,
        filter = Q('messages__status' = status)
    ) for status in statuses
}

mailings = Mailing.objects.annotate(**annotations)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if we have like 50 statuses? Too much repetitive code. But I will try to find a way to use your suggestion in DRYer solution.

Comment: You can create the annotations in a loop - see my updated answer.

Comment: Updated solution is closer to what I'd like to achieve, but how can I group all stats to get them by `.stats` rather than getting list of statuses and iterating over them manually (`mailing.status_1`, `mailing.status_2`)?